# Asp.Net difference between doPostBack & DoPostBackWithOptions

Tags: asp.net

In Asp.Net what is the difference between _doPostBack & DoPostBackWithOptions, In what scenario  _doPostback  &  DoPostBackWithOptions  will be used ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DoPostBackWithOptions is for [MS Ajax/Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx) ie:Using UpdatePanels...etc